# Get *only* file path of files without extension [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, linq, filepath

I'm using a function to get the file paths in my executable path with the extension `txt`.

```
Dim FileEntries as string() = _
Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "*txt"
```

But now i figures out that it would be better to use this files without the txt extension, despite the fact i can use notepad to change the lines anyway.

How do i use this function to get **only** the files without the extension?
If i use only `"*"` it gets all the files, apart from the extension. Thank you!

-EDIT-

I want to avoid any file that it's not suppose to be in the path. I want to gather only the files that have no extension, and therefore avoid any other file. If somehow a file is created there, with any extension, i want to avoid it.

Comment: You could use Linq. Something like `Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "*").Where(Function(x) Not(x.Name.contains(".txt"))` ... Not tested.

Comment: @DanielShillcock what if there's another extension type in the same folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with Linq is to use the `Path.GetExtension()` method to see if the file has an extension:

```
Sub Main
    Dim files = getFilenamesWithNoExtension("C:\SomeFolder")
End Sub

Private Function getFilenamesWithNoExtension(foldertosearch As String) As String()
    Dim result As String()

    result = Directory.EnumerateFiles(foldertosearch).Where(Function(f) String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(f))).ToArray()

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: This is the answer i wanted ! ty

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ:

```
Dim nonTxtFiles = 
    From fn In Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath))
    Where Not String.Equals(Path.GetExtension(fn), ".txt", Stringcomparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
Dim FileEntries as string() = nonTxtFiles.ToArray()
```

---

If you only want files without extensions(you have edited your question), it's easy:

```
Dim noExtFiles = From fn In Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                 Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(IO.Path.GetExtension(fn))
```

Comment: what if there's another extension type in the same folder?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This query returns only files which extension is not.txt

Comment: what about only files without any extension? like avoid `.txt`, `.ini`, `.bmp` or other file extension that it's not suppose to be there..

Comment: Tims answer returns all files that do not have the .txt extension. I believe that's what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DanielShillcock I'm trying to avoid `all` extensions! i just want the files without extension, let's say that "no extension" is a extension and i want to filter by "no extension".

Comment: You can store them in a collection and use Not Contains(...)

Comment: @TimSchmelter and how do i get all possible extensions?